# Accessing a docker container's IP address from a static client

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, apollo-client, hasura

I have a static Gatsby app that needs the uri from another container for a Hasura GraphQL connection.

### The Problem

The Gatsby container finishes the docker build before Hasura's, so the URI in Gatsby is set to `undefined`.

How can I make it so the uri is dynamic and changes to Hasura's actual container IP address when it's done building?

### What I tried

- Add a `depends_on` in `docker-compose.yml` to force Gatsby to wait until the Hasura container is ready, so it'll have the IP by the time Gatsby container starts the build. But according to [0] it doesn't guarantee that Gatsby will wait until Hasura finishes to start itself.
- It suggests adding a custom bash script to force the Gatsby container to wait. If I were to use `wait-for-it.sh`, what should the subcommand be (the command after the wait finishes)?

[0] https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.6'

services:
  database:
    image: postgres:12.2
    container_name: 'postgres-db'
    env_file:
      - database.env
    volumes:
      - ./schema.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/1-schema.sql
      - ./seed.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/2-seed.sql

  hasura:
    image: hasura/graphql-engine:v1.2.1
    restart: on-failure
    container_name: 'hasura'
    depends_on:
      - database
    ports:
      - '8180:8080'
    env_file:
      - hasura.env

  web:
    build: '.'
    image: 'webserver'
    container_name: 'nginx-webserver'
    restart: on-failure
    depends_on:
      - hasura
    ports:
      - '8080:80'
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - .:/app
    env_file:
      - webserver.env
```

webserver.env file

```
NODE_ENV=production
GATSBY_WEBPACK_PUBLICPATH=/
HASURA_ENDPOINT=http://hasura:8080/v1/graphql
```

GraphQL Apollo client that needs the Hasura URI:

```
export const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: process.env.HASURA_ENDPOINT,
  fetch,
});
```

Comment: What I can't figure out is why you need an IP address if you can use `container_name`, which would automatically resolve to the IP address from `/etc/hosts` within the container, since all the containers are automatically on the same network.

Comment: Sorry, that's what I meant when I say IP :). I put the container name `hasura` inside the `webserver.env` file (`http://hasura:8080/v1/graphql`), but it still returns undefined in the app. I think it's because the app container finishes before the other one.

Comment: No, the file `/etc/hosts` should be updated automatically and once the other container is up, it should resolve normally. I suspect the problem is somewhere else, maybe `hasura` is going up and down immediately, putting it into constant restarting state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution.

I was thinking about the container network relationship incorrectly.

The client looks at the HOST'S ip address when connecting, not the container's.

### Explanation

- The Hasura container exposes itself to everyone via `localhost:8180`. If you look at the docker-compose file, port `8180:8080` means "Make Hasura's port 8080 accessible to localhost's port 8180".
- The gatsby app (nginx-webserver) should point to `localhost:8180`, not `hasura:8080`.

My final docker-compose.yml:

```yaml
version: '3.6'

    services:
      database:
        image: postgres:12.2
        container_name: 'postgres-db'
        env_file:
          - database.env
        volumes:
          - ./schema.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/1-schema.sql
          - ./seed.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/2-seed.sql
    
      hasura:
        image: hasura/graphql-engine:v1.2.1
        restart: on-failure
        container_name: 'hasura'
        depends_on:
          - database
        ports:
          - '8180:8080'
        env_file:
          - hasura.env
    
      web:
        build: '.'
        image: 'nginx-webserver'
        container_name: 'web'
        restart: on-failure
        ports:
          - '8080:80'
        volumes:
          - .:/app
          - app/node_modules
        env_file:
          - webserver.env
```

ApolloClient setup:

```js
import ApolloClient from 'apollo-boost';
import fetch from 'isomorphic-fetch';

export const HASURA_ENDPOINT_URI =
  process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'
    ? 'http://localhost:8090/v1/graphql'
    : 'http://localhost:8180/v1/graphql';

export const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: HASURA_ENDPOINT_URI,
  fetch
});
```